# Digits (location/position) vs. digits (glyph/symbol/value) on a display?

Tags: nouns, ambiguity, technical

This is about (numerical) displays, eg. a "multiple-digit" display such as a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display (LED or LCD) and the difference between a digit as a single-glyph numeral (0-9) and a digit as referring to the possible position for a glyph on the display.

Example: "1.23" would be a three-digit display with the digits/glyphs/symbols "1","2","3" with the numeral "1.23" (representing a number).
However, any digit (location) on that display could show different digits (glyph/symbol/value), e.g. the leftmost could show a "9" instead.

So the term "digit" is used ambiguously which makes it a little awkward, and I am looking for a way to distinguish between the two meanings - is there?

---

Edit:

The awkwardness I was referring to may be clearer with yet another example: "Show a digit on the leftmost digit".

I guess it's a matter of context and better set up in a way that "Show a digit on the leftmost position" or similar would work - which is difficult when the context is the positional attribute.

Maybe introducing inaccuracy like "Show a number on the leftmost digit" is tolerable? But it is and sounds wrong.

Wikipedia states nothing about its use as "positional attribute":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit

> A numerical digit is a single symbol (such as "2" or "5") used alone,
>   or in combinations (such as "25"), to represent numbers (such as the
>   number 25) according to some positional numeral systems. The single
>   digits (as one-digit-numerals) and their combinations (such as "25")
>   are the numerals of the numeral system they belong to.

So maybe there is a synonym for "digit" better suited to describe a position - perhaps "place" (from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decimal_place, but not quite right either)?

Comment: Why are *decimal place* or *position* not suited to your purpose?

Comment: @michael It's difficult because the term used to refer to these positions is "digit". "Decimal place" is probably not correct as it is precisely defined as "the position of a digit to the right of the decimal point in a decimal number. "

Comment: While I would recommend "significant figure" to refer to any given point, in reference to your comment above, I believe "digit" refering to the actual contents of the position supercedes the notion of position itself. i.e. "The left-most digit" would always be thought of as the left most lit-up number.

Comment: You need to decide if you want to look at this from a mathematical point of view, or an engineering one. In mathematics, there can be no "empty" digits - so the problem what to call them does not arise. In engineering, each "slot" of 7 segments is usually called "digit" and it displays (or not) a symbol. That said, I would have no problem calling these slots "places" or "positions".

Comment: @michael That's exactly it, the notion of an inactive "slot" (empty display position) also called digit in engineering/tech terminology. Coming from the technical point of view, I think I'll refer to the position as "digit" and whatever is shown there as "symbol" or "glyph" - after all, seven-segment displays are  not limited to numerals and can show quite a number of letters in addition to the hexadecimal A-F. Thank you all for your input and the discussion (I can't upvote, sorry).

Comment: If you insist on using digit in both senses, then you will have to make sure that the context is enough to disambiguate. For example, always talk about "1st digit", "2nd digit" etc. and "the digit 1", "the digit 2" and so on. However, I would avoid "digit" for the latter and refer to numeral or character.

Answer (score -1):

There is no confusion, because a digit is one numeral, whatever numeral it is. For example, '100' is a three-digit number, but so is '199'. It does not matter what numerals are actually displayed, '3' is the maximum number of digits we actually see on a 3-digit display, one per 'live' segment, whether it is to display '1.23', '999', '2' or even 'EEE'.

Therefore a digit is any displayable character in the numeral range 0-9 plus the null display (plus 'E' for error in some systems), and therefore there is no confusion between 'digits' and the numerals actually displayed.

Comment: No, a segment is one of e.g. seven areas that comprise a digit. To show the numeral "1", two segments are activated.

Comment: @Guest - yes, a duh moment there, I was talking about something else completely...

Comment: No problem, but the catch is that I am effectively looking for a synonym of "digit" in the positional sense. I've updated the question, hoping to make myself a bit clearer. And thanks for your interest!

Comment: In these kinds of situations a small diagram is often useful, marked 'display 1', 'display 2' etc.